# Stateless widget's children will not rebuild after a model update when passing said model using Provider

Tags: flutter, provider

[**Please** check this github repository](https://github.com/HeyShafty/ErrorNotificationListener), you can find there *all* the information needed (code, steps to reproduce, expected/actual results, ...) to understand my problem.
*Check the README :)*

This StackOverflow post addresses the `What is not working?` [section from the README file](https://github.com/HeyShafty/ErrorNotificationListener#what-is-not-working).

Nevertheless, here is a preview of my problem:

```dart
class ItemTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ItemModel item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (context) => ItemProvider(item: item),
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          ItemDetailsPage(onNotification: MyPageRoute.onNotification(context), item: item),
        ),
        title: const ItemTileTitle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemTileTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemTileTitle({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final item = context.select<ItemProvider, ItemModel>((provider) => provider.item);

    return Text('ID: ${item.id}, Status: ${item.status}');
  }
}
```

This current widget configuration will **not** rebuild the `ItemTileTitle` whenever the `ItemTile`'s parent rebuilds with a different/updated `item` property.

**Why is that so?**

I am thinking this is an issue related to the widget's lifecycle and how the `ItemTile` will not rebuild its child `ItemTileTitle` because nothing has really changed in the widget tree. Only the `Provider`'s value changed.
But then why is the `context.select` from the `build` method of `ItemTileTitle` not rebuilding if the `Provider`'s value changed?

*More details in the github repository!*: https://github.com/HeyShafty/ErrorNotificationListener

*Also please give me feedback on the way I wrote this post if I am doing anything wrong! Thank you for helping! :)*

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Provider.value` constructor will successfully trigger a rebuild.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider.value(
    value: ItemProvider(item: item),
    child: ListTile(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        ItemDetailsPage(onNotification: MyPageRoute.onNotification(context), item: item),
      ),
      title: const ItemTileTitle(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: However I personally **need** to use the default Provider constructor so I will not put this answer as accepted.